# Promise.all on same array

Tags: javascript, promise

I'm looking at promises-based code that does something like this:

```
var promises = [];
function eventHandler(e)
{
    promises.push(getSomeData(e.opts));

    Promise.all(promises)
        .then(...)
        .then(function()
        {
            promises = [];
        });
}
```

Shouldn't the `Promise.all` based promise execute as many times as the `eventHandler` is called?

EDIT: what's happening here is the event handler gets called a few times and the previous promises are not finished yet. I need a way to be able to extend the list of promises and have only one final `then` run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update, OP has clarified they'd like to wait for all promises added before the original ones resolved as well -`.all` does not do this. Instead you can use thenable chaining.

```
var p = Promise.resolve([]); // create empty array promise, `when` in dojo
function eventHandler(e){
    p = p.then(function(value){ // chain off the last value
        return getSomeData(e.opts).then(function(single){
            return value.push(single); // add to the array
        });
    });
}
```

This will add an item to the array each time the eventHandler is called - every time you `.then` it you will get the *current* values and not the last ones - but you can `.then` it as many times as you'd like. You can for example chain on when no events happened since the chaining time by:

```
var p2 == p;
p.then(function(results){
    if(p !== p2) return p; // wait in case more events happened, but no more
    return results;
});
```

Or wait for as long as you'd like:

```
function noMoreAddedInterim(){
   var p2 = p;
   return p.then(function(results){
       if(p2 !== p) return noMoreAddedInterim(); // changed
       else return results; // no more added
   });
 }
```

---

You have a race condition, you're calling `Promise.all` and only cleaning the array later so many promises are in the results twice or more.

Instead - put `promises` in a temporary variable, `.all` that and clear `promises` before the `.then`. Since you're adding promises one at a time you probably don't even need the `.all` here.

Also, you should attach a .catch handler to not miss any errors.

Comment: Promise.all should operate on a copy of the array so there is no race condition, although Qs `all` mutates the existing array so there is that..

Comment: It is in an event-handler and gets called multiple times, before the promise ever finishes... I need to be able to delay the final `then` if more promises are added while the existing ones are not fulfilled yet. I don't understand how using a copy or a temporary variable would help

Comment: In that case `.all` won't work. Please specify this requirement in your question and I'll edit the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your edit, I am familiar with that pattern of chaining, but I couldn't quite figure out when and how to put the final `then` and to actually react to the last promise only once within the eventHandler. I'll play with your 2nd and 3rd examples and try to understand how they work.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum - in your 2nd and 3rd example - you never reassign the `p` itself, like in the 1st example? Is the `p2` created inside the `eventHandler`? I can't make it work, not in JS and not in my brain :( It either doesn't chain properly or executes the last `then` multiple times when I only want it to happen once

Comment: p is assigned every event handler call - the other code bits demonstrate how that can be used.